# How I can solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need your help to solve this equation:

*Find the solution to the following differential equation:*

$$w_{\xi\xi}+w_{\eta\eta}-4\tan\eta w_{\eta}=0$$

I found this equation when I was solving a second order PDE with the method of the canonical form, but in this step I don´t have idea how I can solve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also include the boundary conditions?

Comment: There is not boundary conditions. This is the canonical form of an exercise that you can find in the book AN INTRODUCTION TO PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS, chapter 3. Exercise 3:6. part b by YEHUDA PINCHOVER AND JACOB RUBINSTEIN

Comment: I think that I got the canonical form which correspond to the above equation, but I don't have any idea how I can solve that equation to answer the part b of the cited exercise.

Comment: In that case you could just use $w(\xi,\eta)=a+b\xi$, since every term would then be zero.

Comment: Then, Is there infinitely solutions?

Comment: In the same book there is another exercises EX: 3.9 with the following statement: Prove that in the elliptic case the canonical transformation is nonsingular. In my case the original equation corresponds to an eliptic equation.

Comment: Yes, because the constants $a$ and $b$ can be chosen freely.

Comment: @fibonatic Thank your very much.